Could a 48V 1000W DC motor with a 5:1 gearing to the wheels, accelerate a mass of 150 kg from stationary to 6.7056 m/s in 5s
I am contemplating building a ride on electric golf buggy using a single 48V DC 1000W motor.
The mass inc golf clubs, batteries and rider would be 150 kg. Driven rear wheel diameter is 330mm.
Gearing on the motor to wheels is flexible within limits, I have chosen an arbitrary 4:1. I would like to accelerate from rest to (15mph) 6.7 m/s in 5s. Also would there be enough torque for the vehicle to negotiate an incline of 30 degrees. Is the gearing adequate?

So 30kg without the rider?

Figure out some approximate losses, and remember that a lot of losses depend on speed.

Your title says 5:1 but the question says 4:1.

yes , as i say the gearing is flexible to a point 4:1 / 5:1 approx, its not built or fully designed yet

@Solar Mike - 100KG for the rider, 15kg golf clubs and bag, 30Kg for the vehicle and batteries - all approx.

The appropriate gear ratio depends on the torque of the motor. Power alone doesn’t address this.

Say with 60% overall efficiency, friction, the gearing, power train, wheels, and rolling dynamic friction,
$$1000\ \mathrm{watts} . 0.6 = 600\ \mathrm{Nm/s}$$
$$\alpha =\frac{change\ of\ speed}{time} = 6.7 / 5 = 1.34\ \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$$
$$150\ \mathrm{kg}.1.34\ \mathrm{ms^{-2}} = 201\ \mathrm {Nm/s} < 600\ \mathrm{Nm/s}$$
So it's ok.

thankyou! just what I wanted.

@AlanTwigg, please accept the answer, so it will be available for future reference to others. thank you.
